# Chrome throws ajaxSetup is not a function when I have imported jquery library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a .js file in which I have defined the following functions:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function( event, request, settings ) {
  alert(request.status);
});

$( document).ajaxError(function( event, request) {
  alert("Display");
});
```

And an .htmml file in which I have included `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

After loading my .html file I inspect the element and I can see there are two event listeners attached to it - Ajax Error and Ajax Success. After I added new interceptor, namely:

```
$( document).ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    alert(settings.data);
    alert(settings.url);
  }
});
```

After adding this interceptor when I load the page it throws an error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ajaxSetup is not a function

Is my sintax incorrect or I am missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like [it says in docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  ...
});
```

instead of

```
$(document).ajaxSetup
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. So I set up ajaxSetup on the whole dom, while, ajaxSuccess and ajaxError on the document?

Comment: Yes, `$.ajaxSetup` is like a globally setting and does not need `document` since `ajaxSuccess` needs jquery object (it's reccommeded to use `document`)